# Optimize SQL Query to reduce execution time

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I have a Query written in MS SQL Server R2. Please help optimizing it. It returns string constructs of data more than 6 Lakhs. and it takes 5-6 mins approx in returning result. Is there any way i can improve this?

Below is my query:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Test]
(    
@UserTypeID int,    
@UserID int,    
@CityID int,    
@OperatorID int,    
@ParameterID int    
)                 
as    
begin    
declare @temp table    
(    
 range decimal(18,2),    
 range2 decimal(18,2),    
 image varchar(50),    
 symbol  varchar(20)    
)    
If(@UserID>0)          
Begin    
--print 'hii'    
 Insert into @temp(range,range2,image,symbol)          
 SELECT     tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range, tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2, tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image,tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol          
 FROM         tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls INNER JOIN          
                      tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id          
 WHERE tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID and tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID and tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1 and tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_id = @UserID          

update @temp set       
range = range2,      
range2 = range      
where symbol = '<'      
End          
Else          
Begin          
 Insert into @temp(range,range2,image,symbol)          
 SELECT     tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range, tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.range2, tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.image,tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.symbol         
 FROM         tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls INNER JOIN          
                      tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork ON tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls.tbl_legend_view_network_id = tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.id          
 WHERE tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.parameter_id = @ParameterID and tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.user_type_id = @UserTypeID and tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork.is_default = 1           

update @temp set       
range = range2,      
range2 = range      
where symbol = '<'      
End          
--select * from @temp          

Select '[' + STUFF(          
 (SELECT    ',{"latitude":"'+ a.lat+ '","longitude":"' + a.long+ '","value":"' +convert(varchar(20),a.value)+ '","image":"' +temp.image +'"}'    
 FROM         (SELECT     tbl_Survey_Details.lat, tbl_Survey_Details.long, tbl_Survey_Details.value          
         FROM          tbl_Survey_Details INNER JOIN          
              tbl_Survey ON tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_survey_id = tbl_Survey.id INNER JOIN          
              tbl_Location ON tbl_Survey.tbl_location_id = tbl_Location.id INNER JOIN          
              tbl_Area ON tbl_Location.tbl_area_id = tbl_Area.id INNER JOIN    
              tbl_City ON tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = tbl_City.id    
WHERE tbl_Survey_Details.tbl_parameter_id = @ParameterID and tbl_Survey.tbl_mobile_operator_id = @OperatorID and tbl_Area.tbl_city_id = @CityID) AS a    
 INNER JOIN @temp temp on a.value between temp.range and temp.range2    
For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') + ']' as data    
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Test] 
(
    @UserTypeID INT,
    @UserID INT,
    @CityID INT,
    @OperatorID INT,
    @ParameterID INT
)
AS BEGIN

    SELECT data = '[' + STUFF((
        SELECT
            ',{"latitude":"' + A.lat + '","longitude":"' + A.long + '","value":"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.value) + '","image":"' + temp.IMAGE + '"}'
        FROM (
            SELECT
                  sd.lat
                , sd.long
                , sd.value
            FROM dbo.tbl_Survey_Details sd
            JOIN dbo.tbl_Survey s ON sd.tbl_survey_id = s.id
            JOIN dbo.tbl_Location l ON s.tbl_location_id = l.id
            JOIN dbo.tbl_Area a ON l.tbl_area_id = a.id
            JOIN dbo.tbl_City c ON a.tbl_city_id = c.id
            WHERE sd.tbl_parameter_id = @ParameterID
                AND s.tbl_mobile_operator_id = @OperatorID
                AND a.tbl_city_id = @CityID
        ) a
        JOIN (
            SELECT  
                  [range] = CASE WHEN symbol = '<' THEN t.range2 ELSE t.[range] END
                , range2 = CASE WHEN symbol = '<' THEN t.[range] ELSE t.range2 END
                , [image] = t.[image]
            FROM dbo.tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork_Dtls t
            JOIN dbo.tbl_Legend_ViewNetwork n ON t.tbl_legend_view_network_id = n.id
            WHERE n.parameter_id = @ParameterID
                AND n.user_type_id = @UserTypeID
                AND n.is_default = 1
                AND (
                        (
                              n.[user_id] = @UserID 
                            AND 
                              @UserID > 0
                        ) 
                        OR 
                          @UserID <= 0
                )
        ) temp ON A.value BETWEEN temp.[range] AND temp.range2
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 1, '') + ']'

END
```

Comment: sorry this one taking more time compared to the one I posted. :(

what can be the other ways to get response as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query in MS SQL Management Studio Query analyser and click the menu Query, Analyse this query in Database tuning advisor it will tell you waht indexes you need to add to optimise the query...

PS for those of us outside south asia a Lakhs is 100, 000

Comment: I tried it and it gave me some recommendations (indexing on survey_details table), i applied all and i got only seconds of difference. Any other possible solution??

Comment: Where was the majority of the time spent? Well thes thing usually take a long time if there are large changes of data. You really want to target 1-10 000 rows at a time so split work the ranges using a a variable you increment. I dont know if its best to split on userID or range, attack the bit that gives the largest percentage in query analyser.

Comment: Post have been shifted to [this link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43553/reduce-clustered-index-seek-cost-sql-server-2008-r2)